# How to detect notification drawer pull?

Tags: javascript

I have created a mobile friendly game for my site and would like to make sure that the game pauses once a user opens their notification drawer/status bar if they're visiting my app on their mobile device. This a web app, so only Javascript is at my disposal.

I've tried adding an `onBlur` listener to a parent component, and although it does detect when a user taps anywhere outside of the screen, the `onBlur` event doesn't fire if I pull down the notification bar.

What are my options here?

[image: practical-carlos-3cfvvz]

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const handleBlur = React.useCallback(() => {
    alert();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      tabIndex={0}
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "beige"
      }}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    ></div>
  );
}
```

I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function (event) {
  if (document.hidden) {
    console.log("hidden");
  } else {
    console.log("visible");
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `beforeunload`?

Comment: @imvain2 the page does not unload when an overlay is opened above the browser?

Comment: You could try setting up [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/), enable monitoring of all events using [`monitorEvents`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/quickly-monitor-events-from-the-console-panel-2/), then see which events fire (if any) when you pull down the notification drawer on your mobile device.

Comment: @devklick Nothing fires. Well, I guess now we know.

Comment: You could maybe try and detect the event yourself by listening for touchstart and touchend events (e.g. touch start at top & touch end around half screen height = user probably pulled notification drawer down). But I have a feeling that since you need to pull down from the top of the device (which is outside of the web page), these events may not fire

Comment: Yup, you're correct in thinking that. The touch event is out of the pages` scope, so it's undetectable

Comment: I have to ask a question to give you a better answer
How the game works? does it uses a loop ? so can you clear that

Comment: @KroKing Doesn't matter if you don't know *when* to clear it